# PAMguard Database-PAMbinary data organisation

Tags: pamguard, pamguard-viewer-mode

I have been proccessing data in PAMguard with the Whistle & Moan Detector and the Noiseband Monitor, and I have two templates depending on the 2 STs sensitivity (only 1 PAM sation).

I decided not to start validating in two different databases because there would be two parallel numerations of the UIDs. So, in PAMguard Viewer I have been opening the PAMbinary folder processed from the noise band templates, but opening it with a different sQlite3 than what it was first processed with.

Is that okay in the long run? Or should I always have the same SQlite3 associated to that PAMbinary folder for the whole process?

I am asking specially because I have been having the pop-up overwriting warning  appearing when I am processing new recordings, eventho when it is new data and the input & output dates should not be overlapping. If I continue with the process, it deletes all the previous files in the PAMbinary folder and empties the database. I know that the problem is somehow coming from the SQlite3 database file but I don't know how to solve that.

[image]

Thank you and cheers!

Comment: Based on what you are seeing with the deleting of all your binaries, I would think it is not a good idea? But I don't really know for sure. For what it's worth, I always create a copy of the database and binaries in a folder called 'original' immediately after finishing processing. that way, if anything I do in viewer mode changes the database in a way I don't want, I can go back without having to re-run detectors.